# Pca of a vector

Tags: google-colaboratory, vectorization, pca

I have a time series data with 4 columns (time, radial, axial and temp) and 900 data points for each column. I have 4 num classes with 10 samples in each class.

I want to convert each sample to a vector of dimension 1*2700, perform pca, then plot the variation in the original sample space and see variations for radial, axial and temperature parameters. How do I do this in python?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html